# Create Underline Transition CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to make a header appear to have an animated *underline* when the parent element is hovered.  Right now it is very close but I can't seem to position it correctly so that its width grows in both directions from its center, which is what I want it to do.  Does someone know what I'm missing or need to add to my code to make this happen?  The code below is what I think is relevant to fixing the situation.  The entire project can be viewed via this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kotsenburg/pen/jwoVWw) as well.  Thanks in advance! (The underlining is only applied to the first header when hovering).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row flex-row">
    <div id="top-image" class="image-block">
        <h3>Fish Tail</h3>

        <div class="underline"></div>

        <img class="flex-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/KSHq0VSqLMA">
    </div>
    <div class="image-block">
        <h3>Swallow Tail</h3>
        <img class="flex-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/U--hvQ5MKjY">
    </div>
    <div class="image-block">
        <h3>Directional</h3>
        <img class="flex-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/F3ePNdQb_Lg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-block:hover > h3{
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.underline {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.image-block:hover .underline {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Edit:**

I am trying to use the same ideas from someone else's [Underlining Effect CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kseso/pen/bfzjC).  The biggest difference is I don't want to have an `<a>` inside my header.

Comment: have you tried centering the start point and having transform statements expand left and right? could be done with `@keyframes` rules

Comment: No I haven't tried it with `@keyframes` yet.  I am basing my code off of this codepen I found. The very first hover effect is what I want.  https://codepen.io/Kseso/pen/bfzjC

Comment: Is this the desired effect? [codepen](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/GvJyQq)

Comment: ah. so in that codepen the author sets the margin like, `margin: 3em auto 0;` which starts the underline point in the middle. in your code change your `margin:0;` to `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Yes @JoeB. , that is exactly the effect I want!

Comment: @Joe B. has the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply `width: 100%` to the `.underline` rule it begins the animation from the center.

```
.underline {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;    /**** Change this to 100% ****/
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

#### Adjusting the width of the line

To adjust the width of the line you can change the following:

```
  .underline{
    margin: 10% /*<== Set to half of 'what's left' in this case half of 20% is 10%*/
    width: 80%;
  }

  .image-block:hover .underline {
    width: 80% /*<== Set to match the .underline width */
  }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  min-width: 100%;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.image-block:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.image-block h3 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 48px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.image-block:hover>h3 {
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.underline {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /**** Change this to 100% ****/
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.image-block:hover .underline {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.flex-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .image-block {
    width: 33.33%%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1660px) {
  .navbar a {
    padding: 14px 14%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1035px) {
  .navbar a {
    padding: 14px 12%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 880px) {
  #top-image {
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
  .image-block {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .navbar a:hover {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row flex-row">
  <div id="top-image" class="image-block">
    <h3>Fish Tail</h3>
    <div class="underline">
    </div>
    <img class="flex-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/KSHq0VSqLMA">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works great! Do you know how I might have it expand to about only 80% of the container while keeping it centered as it is by chance?

Comment: You can change the width in `.underline` to 80% and also change the width on `.image-block:hover .underline` to 80%. Lastly, change the `margin-left` in `.underline` to `10%` I updated [this pen](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/GvJyQq)